# Get the latest download link using Curl

Tags: bash, curl, wget

I am trying to use curl to download the latest linux link from here: https://redream.io/download

The most recent download link is: https://redream.io/download/redream.x86_64-linux-v1.5.0-1106-g01ef607.tar.gz

The next one is: https://redream.io/download/redream.x86_64-linux-v1.5.0-1101-g8b51a07.tar.gz and so on.

It looks like they can be sorted by the 1106, 1101, 1093 numbers. So I'd be using curl to grab whatever the highest 4 digit number (specifically the linux version) is.

I've tried modifying this block from an older thread but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
 # Determine latest version:
 latestVer=$(curl 'http://nginx.org/download/' | 
   grep -oP 'href="nginx-\K[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' | 
   sort -t. -rn -k1,1 -k2,2 -k3,3 | head -1)

 # Download latest version:
 curl "http://nginx.org/download/nginx-${latestVer}.tar.gz" > nginx-latest.tar.gz
```

I have this at the moment:

```
latestVer=$(curl 'https://redream.io/download' |
    grep -oP 'href="redream.x86-64-linux-v1.5.0-\K[0-9]+\[0-9]+\[0-9]+\[0-9]+' |
    sort -t. -rn -k1,1 -k2,2 -k3,3, -k4,4 | head -1)


curl "https://redream.io/download/redream.x86-64-linux-v1.5.0-${latestVer}.tar.gz" > redream.tar.gz
```

I would ideally like v1.5.0 to not be hardcoded either but using a wildcard doesn't seem to work.

Any pointers?

Comment: Using `grep` to parse HTML is a serious code smell. For example, the link could change from `href="` to `HREF=` or `href = "`, or could even put a linebreak between the `href` and the `=`, and all of these would be equally correct HTML, but your regex would break. Use tools that actually understand HTML, and your code won't be sensitive to formatting. (It'll also eliminate a multitude of other failure modes, like content that's commented out still being matched).

Comment: `xmllint` can convert (X)HTML to real XML, at which point you can use `xmllint --xpath` or xmlstarlet or any of the other multitude of available tools to run queries against the content.

Comment: some suggestions re: basic debugging ... run `curl` and capture output to a file (eg, `download.html`), then work on getting the `grep` to work against the file, then work on the `sort`; the current `grep` is not pulling anything if simply because `href="redream.x86-64-linux` does not match anything in the actual html file

Comment: Beyond that, a Stack Overflow question that refers to data from an external site _that that site is liable to change at any time_ defeats our goal of building a long-lived knowledge base: We want people to be able to learn from your question's answers 10 years from now, but if redream.io disappears in that time nobody will be able to reproduce the problem. You can avoid that by making sure everything needed to reproduce the problem, including a [mre] with the shortest possible subset of HTML contents that you expect your grep to handle correctly but that it doesn't really support, is included.

Comment: Get latest version number from top of https://redream.io/changelog and use it to download latest stable version from https://redream.io/download .

Answer (score 1):

[It's really a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454) [to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/590747) [with RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6751105). Please use an HTML-parser like [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) instead:

```
$ xidel -s "https://redream.io/download" -e '
  //div[@class="my-5" and h2="Development Releases"]/ul/div[1]/ul/li/a[contains(@href,"x86_64-linux")]/resolve-uri(@href)
'
https://redream.io/download/redream.x86_64-linux-v1.5.0-1106-g01ef607.tar.gz
```

*(`div[1]`: assuming the latest development release is listed first)*

`xidel` can also download the archive for you, so there's actually no need for `curl`:

```
$ xidel "https://redream.io/download" -f '
  //div[@class="my-5" and h2="Development Releases"]/ul/div[1]/ul/li/a[contains(@href,"x86_64-linux")]/resolve-uri(@href)
' --download .
```

This will download and save *'redream.x86_64-linux-v1.5.0-1106-g01ef607.tar.gz'* to the current dir.